# Perl to format csv file and count occurances and put into rows

Tags: perl, csv, count, format

I am trying to write a perl script that takes in csv eg.

score,id
  1,6833
  0.508201,2759
  0.587154,2759
  0.845473,2759
  0.882188,33630

And outputs eg.

id,score,abundance
6833,1,1
2759,0.508201,0.845473,1,3
33630,0.882188,1

Only take lines that are >=0.5 by column 1. And By column 2 which repeats like 2759 is, gather the scores after it. The last number is the abundance for eg 2759 which is present 3 times.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open( my $csv, "$ARGV[0]" ) or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";
open( my $csv_spp, ">$ARGV[0]_spp_ML.csv" );

while ( my $line = <$csv> ) {
    my ( $ml, $id ) = split( /,/, $line );
    if ( $ml >= 0.5 ) {

        if ( $id = $id ) {
            my $count++;
        }

        print $csv_spp $id, $count;
    }
}
close($csv);
close($csv_spp);
```

I am stuck at how to get the numbers to follow or count occurrence.

Comment: `if($id = $id){` should be `==`. all you're doing is assigning $id to itself, which is utterly pointless.

Comment: Your first step is to indent your code properly so that you can see where blocks begin and end

Comment: @MarcB: No more pointless that testing whether it's equal toi itself, which is what you're suggesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if ( $id = $id ) {
    my $count++;
}
```

This ... is nonsense. `$count` is lexically scoped, so right after you 'increment' it, it then... goes out of scope and disappears again.

Also, testing if `$id = $id` - even if you meant `==` you're testing if something is equal to itself. (And if you didn't, you're testing if you could assign something to itself, which makes less sense).

What you might be meaning is to use a hash to count your occurences, and you'd probably need another hash of arrays to collate your values.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open( my $csv, '<', "$ARGV[0]" ) or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";
open( my $csv_spp, '>', "$ARGV[0]_spp_ML.csv" );

my %count_of; 
my %values_of; 

while ( my $line = <$csv> ) {
    chomp; 
    my ( $ml, $id ) = split( /,/, $line );
    if ( $ml >= 0.5 ) {
        $count_of{$id}++; 
        push ( @{$values_of{$id}}, $id );
    }
}
close($csv);

foreach my $id ( sort keys %count_of ) {
   print {$csv_spp} join ( ",", $id, @{$values_of{$id}}, $count_of{$id} ),"\n";
}

close($csv_spp);
```

You might also want to consider using `Text::CSV` to read your file too.